# How to create a better visualization from a scatterplot with a lot of points?

Tags: r, ggplot2

so I am trying to ggplot scatter plot with x-axis as the population which is current_votes, and y-axis as the percentage of votes for the population, colored by the candidate, either Joe Biden, or Trump. However, the number of points are all bunched up together at the top. How can I make it so that the points are evenly spread out if there are too many points?

```
scatter_c <- function(new_data) {
  f <- ggplot(data = new_data, aes(x = percentage_votes, y = current_votes, color = candidate)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_manual(
      values = c("Donald Trump" = alpha("blue",0.3), "Joe Biden" = alpha("red",0.3))
      ) +
    coord_flip()
  return(f)
}


scatter_c(data_4)
```

[image: Scatter graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
scatter_c <- function(new_data) {
 
 ggplot(data = new_data, aes(x = current_votes, y = percentage_votes, color = candidate)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(
   values = c("Donald Trump" = alpha("blue",0.3), "Joe Biden" = alpha("red",0.3))
   ) +
  scale_x_log10()
 
}

library(ggplot2)
scatter_c(data_4)
```

I've removed `coord_flip` and simply inverted `x` and `y` in `aes`. Then I've used `scae_x_log10` to get the expected result.

---

Just as a suggestion...

The perfect charts depends on what the goal of you analysis is. In this graph you are mixing percentages between each other...

Also, aren't republicans usually red and democrats blue?

Comment: Oh that helped so much! I will keep that in mind! I totally forgot about republicans being red and democrats blue haha. Never thought of that!